# Compass Pointing To Player: Minecraft Bedrock Add-On

Tags: minecraft

I am building an Addon to point a compass to another player constantly, and I do not want to do this via command blocks. I think I should use .MCFUNCTION files, but I am not sure. What should I do? I have already tried searching Google, but there seems to be no information on building add-ons.

**This is for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition 1.16.**

The command I would use is `/execute <playerName> ~ ~ ~ setworldspawn ~ ~ ~`. What this means is is will execute the `setworldspawn ~ ~ ~` command on behalf of whoever `<playerName>` is. Then, the `~ ~ ~` means it would set the spawn to the player. Compasses always point to the spawn, and if this command was executed every tick, anyone with a compass could track the person because the person is at spawn.

Another question: Is there a way to make a command that lets players set who the `<playerName>` is? I don't need that to be in, but it would be nice if it was a possibility.

Is the tick.json the way to go? I cannot seem to find any information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little late, but you can set the player! Not in the way you might think, though. Let's say this is our original code: `execute JohnUsername ~ ~ ~ spawnpoint`
What you can actually do is use tags: `execute @a[tag=targ] ~ ~ ~ spawnpoint`
Now a player has to just do `/tag @s add targ` and they will become the target.
So you can have the player do this. One problem: You have to make sure to do `/tag @s remove targ` if you wanna switch. How do you counteract this? Make a function like this: [targetme.mcfunction]
`tag @a remove targ`
`tag @p add targ`
Now whenever i run /function targetme in the chat, I become the target and it takes away the target from whoever was before, and if no ones the target it still works and just gives me target. Sadly you can't do like /function targetadd Jim though :(. You need the player that wants to be hunter to run the function. (Or you can set up a system that selects a random player, such as replace `tag @p add targ` with `tag @r add targ` and when the function gets run someone is randomly selected)